# Proof that $\langle T,\varphi \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \varphi^{(k)} (\sqrt 2)$ is not a distribution.

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory

Define $\langle T, \cdot \rangle: C_0 ^\infty (\mathbb R) \to \mathbb C$ such that $\langle T,\varphi \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \varphi^{(k)} (\sqrt 2)$.

I'm trying to proof that $\langle T, \cdot \rangle$ does not define a distribution.

I have the following hint: Consider the function $\varphi = e^{x - \sqrt 2}$.

Since $\varphi ^{(k)} (\sqrt 2) = 1$ for all $k$, we'll have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \varphi^{(k)} (\sqrt 2) = \infty$. However $e^{x - \sqrt 2} \notin C_0 ^\infty (\mathbb R)$. I hear that I can approximate this function by test functions, althoug I don't know how to do it.

Help?

Comment: The point is that there is a $C^\infty_0$ function which agrees with $\varphi$ on, say, $[1,2]$ (or whatever other neighborhood of $\sqrt{2}$ you like). Do you know how to construct it?

Comment: @Ian No, my problem is how to construct that function.

Comment: Look up "bump functions", they are the standard way to achieve such constructions.